# Python .strip () Does Not Remove Blank Lines

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to read in a string from a text file and remove empty or blank lines at the end of the file using .strip () but it doesn't seem to work.  However, testing inside the interactive mode works as expected.

**Example of a text file called nameList:**

```
Bob 555-333-4444
Sam 234-343-1234
<blank line>
```

**Using interactive mode output:**

```
>>> str = 'Bob 555-333-4444\nSam 234-343-1234\n'
>>> print (str)
Bob 555-333-4444
Sam 234-343-1234

>>> newStr = str.strip ()
>>> print (newStr)
Bob 555-333-4444
Sam 234-343-1234
>>>
```

**Using an open function to read the text file:**

```
list = []

def readStr ():

        f = open ('nameList.txt', 'r')

        for line in f:
                row = line.strip ()
                print (row)

        f.close ()
```

**Output from the readStr () function:**

```
>>> readStr ()
Bob 555-333-4444
Sam 234-343-1234

>>>
```

Does it have something to do with the "open/read" function?

Comment: Your two snippets are doing different things, why expect the same results?

Comment: perhaps you'd prefer to skip the `for` loop entirely and just do `print f.read().strip()`

Comment: Are you saying the .strip () function doesn't work the same when it's in the interactive mode versus being called in a function?  I ultimately wanted to put it in a list so I can process each parameter that's why I didn't use the f.read ().

Comment: @dreamzboy: What jonrsharpe is telling you is that stripping one by one line is different from stripping one multiline string. The problem is that even an empty line is converted back to the newline when using `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.strip()` only removes whitespace from the ends of the string. With

```
'Bob 555-333-4444\nSam 234-343-1234\n'.strip()
```

the issue is not that you are using it interactively, but that you have multiple lines (text separated by the `\n` characters) in a *single* string. The result is

```
'Bob 555-333-4444\nSam 234-343-1234'
```

after stripping the final newline character.

In your other example, you are calling `strip` on a series of individual strings that consist of a single line, i.e., the only newline is at the end of the string. You then print the result. Even though `'\n'.strip () == ''`, the result is still a string, just an empty one, which when printed by `print(row)` produces a blank line (the empty string plus the newline supplied by `print`).

Comment: Your explanation makes a whole lot of sense now.  Thank you!  Any idea how I go about removing that empty string before appending to a list?

Comment: Just check if it is empty before appending: `if row != '': print(row)`.

Answer (score 0):

first you do not want to overwrite **str** it is a builtin and you need it intact.
second, you do not want to overwrite list with a slightly different kind of list;
so use something like **mylist = [None,]** instead.

```
def readStr ():
        mylist = []
        with open('nameList.txt', 'r')  as f:
            mydata = f.read()

        mydata.split('\n')
        for line in mydata:
            line2 = line.strip()
            if not line2: continue
            # now you have a list with no empty lines.
            mylist.append(line2)

readStr()
```

You need to read the data before you can loop over it. The above code will solve your problem by splitting the data after it has been read. The last line will be blank and will be continue before it is printed. Your problem may have been that your last line is `''` and when your strip it you still get `''` so you would need to check `if not line2: continue`

Comment: He did not overwrite `str`. Your answer does not address the question

Comment: str = 'Bob 555-333-4444\nSam 234-343-1234\n' and list = [] and overwriting str and list respectively. This is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The line.strip() is to remove any /r or /n on operating systems where it is
irrelevant. it also removes any lines with only blank spaces.

```
mylist = []
def readStr():
    with open('nameList.txt', 'r') as f:
        readstr = f.read()
    mylist = readstr.split('\n')
    for line in mylist:
        # strip any unwanted spaces etc.
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '': continue
        print(line)
    print(str(mylist))
```

I changed list = [] to mylist = [] to prevent overwriting the builtin list which creates a list as well as other things to do with lists.

Aven Desta: You do not want to overwrite str or any other builtins. The code works fine. I do not know who gave me -1 for legit help.